# How can I extract font color of text within a PDF in Python with PDFMiner?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

How can I extract font color from text within a PDF?

I already tried to explore `LTText` or `LTChar` objects using PDFMiner, but it seems that this module only allows to extract font size and style, not color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDFMiner's LTChar object has 'graphicstate' attribute which has 'scolor' (stroking color) and 'ncolor' (non stroking color) attributes, which can be used to obtain text color information. Here's working code snippet (based on the code from one of the answers) that outputs font info for each text line component:

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextContainer, LTChar
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as scr_file:
    for page_layout in extract_pages(scr_file):
        for element in page_layout:
            if isinstance(element, LTTextContainer):
                fontinfo = set()
                for text_line in element:
                    for character in text_line:
                        if isinstance(character, LTChar):
                            fontinfo.add(character.fontname)
                            fontinfo.add(character.size)
                            fontinfo.add(character.graphicstate.scolor)
                            fontinfo.add(character.graphicstate.ncolor)
                print("\n", element.get_text(), fontinfo)
```

Comment: colors are in what form? RGB? CMYK? I tried to convert them but it none resemble the actual color in PDF

Answer (score 7):

I looked at all the source code for [PDFMiner](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer) (not maintained) and [PDFMiner.Sixth](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six) (fork). Neither *Python* module allows you extract the color. Within the issues section for both modules extracting the font color is a common problem.

I also looked at [PDFPlumber](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber), which uses PDFMiner.Sixth.  The module  extract font colors. The color elements extracted included the *stroking_color,* which is the outline of a character and the *non_stroking_color,* which is the fill of a character. I looked at the colors extracted from my sample PDF and they matched the RGB colors.

```
import pdfplumber

pdf_file = pdfplumber.open('path_to_pdf')
for p, char in zip(pdf_file.pages, pdf_file.chars):
    words = p.extract_words(keep_blank_chars=True)
    texts = p.extract_text()
    print(f"Page Number: {p.page_number}")
    print(f"Font Name: {char['fontname']}")
    print(f"Font Size: {char['size']}")
    print(f"Stroking Color: {char['stroking_color']}")
    print(f"Non_stroking Color: {char['non_stroking_color']}")
    print(texts.strip())
    print('\n')
```

**The unanswered question is:**

*How can you extract the font colors and still use your PDFMiner code?*

The code below allows me to simultaneously use *PDFMiner.Sixth* and *PDFPlumber* to extract various elements, such as the text, font name, font size, stroking_color and non_stroking_color from the source PDF file.

```
import pdfplumber

from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextContainer, LTChar


with open('path_to_pdf', 'rb') as scr_file:
    with pdfplumber.PDF(scr_file) as pdf_file:
        for page_layout, char in zip(extract_pages(scr_file), pdf_file.chars):
            for element in page_layout:
                if isinstance(element, LTTextContainer):
                    for text_line in element:
                        for character in text_line:
                            if isinstance(character, LTChar):
                                print(element.get_text())
                                print(f"Font Name: {character.fontname}")
                                print(f"Font Size: {character.size}")
                                print(f"Stroking Color: {char['stroking_color']}")
                                print(f"Non_stroking Color: {char['non_stroking_color']}")
                                print('\n\n')
```

### UPDATE 03-09-2021

I'm still working on meshing and synchronizing these functions together. I checked them and they seem to be outputting the correct elements.

```
import pdfplumber
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextContainer, LTChar, LAParams


def extract_character_characteristics(pdf_file):
    number_of_pages = len(list(extract_pages(pdf_file)))
    for page_layout in extract_pages(pdf_file, laparams=LAParams()):
        print(f'Processing Page: {number_of_pages}')
        number_of_pages -= 1
        for element in page_layout:
            if isinstance(element, LTTextContainer):
                for text_line in element:
                    for character in text_line:
                        if isinstance(character, LTChar):
                            if character.get_text() != ' ':
                                print(f"Character: {character.get_text()}")
                                print(f"Font Name: {character.fontname}")
                                print(f"Font Size: {character.size}")
                                print('\n')


def extract_character_colors(pdf_file):
    with pdfplumber.PDF(pdf_file) as file:
        for char in file.chars:
            if char['text'] != ' ':
                print(f"Page Number: {char['page_number']}")
                print(f"Character: {char['text']}")
                print(f"Font Name: {char['fontname']}")
                print(f"Font Size: {char['size']}")
                print(f"Stroking Color: {char['stroking_color']}")
                print(f"Non_stroking Color: {char['non_stroking_color']}")
                print('\n')


with open('test.pdf', 'rb') as scr_file:
    extract_character_characteristics(scr_file)
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to work (you are always using the first char from pdf_file.chars), however it was useful for me to develop a working solution

Comment: @VitoGentile I have used PDFMiner before, but PDFPlumber was new to me.  I will have to look into the "first char" issue too.  I will post an update once I do some more research.

Comment: @VitoGentile I'm still trying to mesh these two function together, but the data from both seems to be accurate.

Answer (score 2):

(disclaimer: I am the author of `pText`, the library being used in this example.)

`pText` allows you to register an `EventListener` that will be notified whenever a PDF rendering instruction (such as rendering text) has been processed.

Upon receiving this instruction you can inspect the graphics state to figure out what the current stroke/fill color are. The text should be rendered using the stroke color.

Let's have a look at how that works:

```
with open("input.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file_handle:
    l = ColorSpectrumExtraction()
    doc = PDF.loads(pdf_file_handle, [l])
```

The above code opens a PDF document for (binary) reading, and calls the `PDF.loads` method. The extra parameter we are passing is an array (in this case of 1 element) of `EventListener` implementations.

Let's look into `ColorSpectrumExtraction`:

```
class ColorSpectrumExtraction(EventListener):

    def event_occurred(self, event: Event) -> None:
        if isinstance(event, ChunkOfTextRenderEvent):
            self._render_text(event)

    def _render_text(self, event: ChunkOfTextRenderEvent):
        assert event is not None
        c = event.font_color.to_rgb()
        // do something with the font-color
```

As you can see, this class has a method `event_occurred`, which will get called on rendering content. In our case, we are only interested in `ChunkOfTextRenderEvent`.

So we verify (using `isinstanceof`) and then delegate the call to another method.

In the method `_render_text` we can then get all the information we want from the text that was just rendered. Like the `font_color`, `font_size`, etc

You can obtain pText either on [GitHub](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release), or using [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/ptext-joris-schellekens/)
There are a ton more [examples](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md), check them out to find out more about working with images.

Comment: This is definitely interesting. However it's a bit complicated for me to use pText in my project, because my impression is that I would need to completely replace pdfminer with pText. And this is not feasible... Is there a way to use this listener idea in combination with PDFminer? If so, I might try to attach some code in my answer, to better understand how to combine pText-based color detection and PDFminer text extraction